# Deploying a cakePHP app on cpanel

Tags: cakephp, deployment, cpanel

I need guidance on how to host a cakephp app on cpanel. Apparently when I put my app on  a shared server I get an error missing controller and yet all was well when running the app on localhost. please help

Comment: Did you change the base path and database credentails?

Comment: I run many Cake apps on cpanel. You don't need to make any config changes. You know to add more detail: the url, the full error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

cPanel is just a control panel for your box and makes to change set to Apache or light speed that you couldn't do without it.  That being said, the only things I would check first would be to check your database connection, makes sure your server has `mod_rewrite` enabled and that you're using a compatible version of php for cakephp AND your plugins.